# Can I use <a> tag button classes in fade in/out JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery image thumb Slider in which each thumb is an "an tag button that links to different div elements.

When a user clicks on a thumb button, I would like the associated div to animate fading in and when the user clicks on another, the previous div should fade out and fade in/replace with the next.

I'm brand new to jQuery and I have spent a lot of time on researching the use of this function that I'm getting confused with the MANY solutions out there.

I feel like I'm missing something in the code but I don't know what.

Below is what I have so far:

CSS

Slider

```
#aemcSlider {
    list-style:none;
    margin-left: 289px;
    width: 474px;
    height: 97px;
    top: 134px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: -3px;
}
#aemcSlider a {
    margin-right: -4px;
}
#aemcPkgContainer {
    z-index:1;
    width: 425px;
    height: 675px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    top: 233px;
}
#aemcGroundAdContainer {
    z-index:2;
    display: none;
    width: 425px;
    height: 675px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    top: 233px;
}
#aemcClampOnAdContainer {
    z-index:3;
    display: none;
    width: 425px;
    height: 675px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    top: 233px;
}
#aemcMetrixContainer {
    z-index:4;
    display: none;
    width: 425px;
    height: 675px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    top: 233px;
}
```

Buttons

//4 buttons like this//

```
a.aemcGroundFlexBut {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 162px;
    height: 114px;
    background: url(../Images/AEMC_AD_6472-74.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
a.aemcGroundFlexBut:hover {
    background-position: 0 -114px;
}
```

HTML

Jquery Slider

```
<div id="aemcSlider">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="aemcPkgBut" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="aemcGroundFlexBut" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="aemcClampBut" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="aemcMetrixBut" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Containers:

//There are 4 containers like this//

```
<div id="aemcPkgContainer">
    <div class="workImage">
        <img src="Images/AEMC_packaging_image.png" alt="Packaging"    
width="295"  hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" title="Packaging"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

// JavaScript Document

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".aemcPkgBut").click(function () {
        $("#aemcGroundAdContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcClampOnAdContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcMetrixContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcPkgContainer").fadeIn(2500);
    });

    $(".aemcGroundFlexBut").click(function () {
        $("#aemcPkgContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcClampOnAdContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcMetrixContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcGroundAdContainer").fadeIn(2500);
    });

    $(".aemcClampBut").click(function () {
        $("#aemcPkgContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcGroundAdContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcMetrixContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcClampOnAdContainer").fadeIn(2500);
    });

    $(".aemcMetrixBut").click(function () {
        $("#aemcPkgContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcGroundAdContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcClampOnAdContainer").fadeOut(2500);
        $("#aemcMetrixContainer").fadeIn(2500);
    });
});
```

This above is not working.

I'm using  tag buttons ...could that be the problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.

thank you!

Comment: How about formatting the code better, and reducing it to relevant parts? Will bring you more answers..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that should be a problem... I tried to use your code to replicate the behavior.

Check this Fiddle out... Hope that helps.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitjc/kTCcT/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".aA").click(function () {
        $('#A').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#B').fadeOut(1000);
    });



    $(".aB").click(function () {
        $('#A').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#B').fadeIn(1000);
    }); });
```

Comment: Thank you for this...unfortunately I still don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Were you able to open the hyperlink? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ankitjc/kTCcT/1/

Comment: Yes, but the replicated problem that you are demonstrating is not what I see from my browser. Currently, I see no functionality at all from the code I'm working with.

Comment: I just tried to answer your question, that yes, we can use <a> tag button classes to call fadeIn/fadeOut of jquery. Thats exactly what the example does. Since I dont have the complete code of urs, my intention is to clear a roadblock while you debug your code.